# Open url in Chrome and close Safari tab

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, safari

I found this code on the Internet:

```
javascript:location.href="googlechrome"+location.href.substring(4);
```

If that code is put in a bookmark in Safari, it will open the Chrome browser and load the current webpage the user had in Safari.

But what I want is when the user clicks on the bookmark, the tab will close in Safari before opening in Chrome. Is that a possibility?

Comment: You can try something along the lines of `javascript:location.href="googlechrome"+location.href.substring(4)+';close()` (I haven't tested this).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.close()` to close the current tab.

`javascript:location.href="googlechrome"+location.href.substring(4); window.close();`

Please note though, the way you are parsing the URL won't work if your url starts w/ `https://` instead of `http://`.

Here's an example that uses the [URI.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) to replace the protocol in the current URL with googlechrome, which should be more reliable than just using `location.href.substring(4)`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/URI.js/1.7.2/URI.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function closeSafariAndOpenChrome()
      {
        var chromeProtocol = 'googlechrome';
        var redirectedUrl = URI(location.href)
           .protocol(chromeProtocol);
        location.href = redirectedUrl;
        window.close();
      }
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <a href="javascript:closeSafariAndOpenChrome();">Click here to open chrome</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `close()` should work because `window` is the default global object, so `window.close()` and just `close()` are functionally equivalent